# Pass parameter at the end of a dot string

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I'm trying to make a function to get one field from a firebase database

```
function getFromDatabase(param1) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log(user)
            db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).get().then(function (doc) {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    console.log(doc.data().name) //Passes expected value
                    console.log(doc.data().param1)
                } else {
                    console.warn("No such document!");
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

when I call

`getFromDatabase(name)`

I would like it to return

`console.log(doc.data().name)`

but it doesn't interpret it as a parameter

I've tried a whole bunch of different variations of `console.log(doc.data().param1)`, but I can't figure this out for the life of me, and it might be because I don't know the correct term to search for, as everything I know is from internet searches.

If anyone could provide insight on what im doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: you want to use bracket notation to use the variable as the key, eg `data()[param1]`

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @PatrickEvans !

`getFromDatabase('name')`
with
`console.log(doc.data()[param1]);`

Gave the expected result.